# MongoDB: Delete item inside multiple objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to delete an item inside an object categorized inside multiple keys. 
for example, deleting ObjectId("c") from every items section

This is the structure:

```
    {
      "somefield" : "value",
      "somefield2" : "value",
      "objects" : {
        "/" : {
           "color" : "#112233",
           "items" : [ 
             ObjectId("c"),
             ObjectId("b")
          ]
        },
        "/folder1" : {
           "color" : "#112233",
           "items" : [
             ObjectId("c"),
             ObjectId("d")
          ]
        },
        "/folder2" : {
           "color" : "112233",
           "items" : []
        },
        "/testing" : {
           "color" : "112233",
           "items" : [ 
             ObjectId("c"), 
             ObjectId("f")
          ]
       }
     }
    }
```

I tried with pull and unset like:

```
    db.getCollection('col').update(
      {},
      { $unset: { 'objects.$.items': ObjectId("c") } },
      { multi: true }
    )
```

and

```
    db.getCollection('col').update(
      {},
      { "objects": {"items": { $pull: [ObjectId("c")] } } },
      {  multi: true }
    )
```

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is largely with the current structure of your document. MongoDB cannot "traverse paths" in an efficient way, and your structure currently has an "Object" ( 'objects' ) which has named "keys". What this means is that accessing "items" within each "key" needs the explicit path to each key to be able to see that element. There are no wildcards here:

```js
 db.getCollection("coll").find({ "objects./.items": Object("c") })
```

And that is the basic principle to "match" something as you cannot do it "across all keys" without resulting to JavaScript code, which is really bad.

Change the structure. Rather than "object keys", use "arrays" instead, like this:

```js
{
   "somefield" : "value",
   "somefield2" : "value",
   "objects" : [
      {
        "path": "/", 
        "color" : "#112233",
        "items" : [ 
            "c",
            "b"
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/folder1",
        "color" : "#112233",
        "items" : [
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/folder2",
        "color" : "112233",
        "items" : []
      },
      {
        "path": "/testing",
        "color" : "112233",
        "items" : [ 
            "c", 
            "f"
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

It's much more flexible in the long run, and also allows you to "index" fields like "path" for use in query matching.

However, it's not going to help you much here, as even with a consistent query path, i.e:

```js
 db.getCollection("coll").find({ "objects.items": Object("c") })
```

Which is better, but the problem still persists that is it not possible to [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from multiple sources ( whether object or array ) in the same singular operation. And that is augmented with "never" across multiple documents.

So the best you will ever get here is basically "trying" the "muti-update" concept until the options are exhausted and there is nothing left to "update". With the "modified" structure presented then you can do this:

```js
var bulk = db.getCollection("coll").initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0,
    modified = 1;

while ( modified != 0 ) {
  bulk.find({ "objects.items": "c"}).update({
    "$pull": { "objects.$.items": "c" }
  });
  count++;

  var result = bulk.execute();
  bulk = db.getCollection("coll").initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  modified = result.nModified;
}

print("iterated: " + count);
```

That uses the ["Bulk" operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) ( actually all shell methods now use it anyway ) to basically get a "better write response" that gives you useful information about what actually happened on the "update" attempt.

The point is that is basically "loops" and tries to match a document based on the "query" portion of the update and then tries to `$pull` from the matched array index an item from the "inner array" that matches the conditions given to `$pull` ( which acts as "query" in itself, just upon the array items ).

On each iteration you basically get the "nModified" value from the response, and when this is finally `0`, then the operation is complete.

On the sample ( restructured ) given then this will take `4` iterations, being one for each "outer" array member. The updates are "multi" as implied by bulk `.update()` ( as opposed to `.updateOne()` ) already, and therefore the "maximum" iterations is determined by the "maximum" array elements present in the "outer" array across the whole collection. So if there is "one" document out of "one thousand" that has `20` entries then the iterations will be `20`, and just because that document still has something that can be matched and modified.

---

The alternate case under your current structure does not bear mentioning. It is just plain "impossible" without:

1. Retrieving the document individually
2. Extracting the present keys
3. Running an individual `$pull` for the array under that key
4. Get next document, rinse and repeat

So "multi" is "right out" as an option and cannot be done, without some some possible "foreknowledge" of the possible "keys" under the "object" key in the document.

---

So please "change your structure" and be aware of the general limitations available.

You cannot possibly do this in "one" update, but at least if the maximum "array entries" your document has was "4", then it is better to do "four" updates over a "thousand" documents than the "four thousand" that would be required otherwise.

---

Also. Please do not "obfuscate" the `ObjectId` value in posts. People like to "copy/paste" code and data to test for themselves. Using something like `ObjectId("c")` which is **not** a valid `ObjectId` value would clearly cause errors, and therefore is not practical for people to use.

Do what "I did" in the listing, and if you want to abstract/obfuscate, then do it with "plain values" just as I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that you could take is using JavaScript native methods like **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** to create the documents that will be used in the update.
You essentially need an operation like the following:

```
var itemId = ObjectId("55ba3a983857192828978fec");

db.col.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var update = {
        "object./.items": itemId, 
        "object./folder1.items": itemId, 
        "object./folder2.items": itemId, 
        "object./testing.items": itemId
    };
    db.col.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        {
            "$pull": update
        }
    );    
})
```

Thus to create the update object would require the **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method that converts an array into an object:

```
var update = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc.objects).reduce(function(o, v, i) {
    o["objects." + v + ".items"] = itemId;
    return o;
}, {});
```

Overall, you would need to use the **[Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** operations to achieve the above update:

```
var bulk = db.col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    itemId = ObjectId("55ba3a983857192828978fec"),
    count = 0;

db.col.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var update = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc.objects).reduce(function(o, v, i) {
        o["objects." + v + ".items"] = itemId;
        return o;
    }, {});
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$pull": update
    })
    count++;
    if (count % 1000 == 0) {            
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if (count % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```